# Clicking on a notification while the app is closed does not open the app

Tags: android, delphi, location, android-notifications

I developed a geofence app, which uses a service to track location, even when the app is closed.

I tried to close the app and lock the screen, and the notification started anyway when I entered the relevant areas.

But I have this problem:

If the app is closed, clicking on the notification does not open the app. It just clears the notification and that's it.

Do you know why, when clicking on the notification while the app is closed, doesn't open the app?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code part, the code which creates and launches the notification?

Comment: I started from the Kastri geofence demo. The only thing that I put in the service is notification when it happens: arrived and departed.
it also works with the app closed, but clicking on the notification, if the app is closed, does not open it, to show detailed information on the place reached.

Comment: You have to edit your question, not misunderstand comments as chat.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code you are using the launch the foreground service notification. We cannot assist you if you do not give us anything to assist on.